# how to count and add to file before delete *.txt files in linux?

Tags: linux, batch-file

I have a few *.txt files in a folder. I want to count and add to deleted_files_count.log file before delete files by using this command:

```
find ./*.txt -type f -mmin +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

For example folder has 3 *.txt files and content of deleted_files_count.log file is 5, content of deleted_files_count.log should be 8 after delete. Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cnt=`cat deleted_files_count.log` ; for i in `find ./*.txt -type f -mmin +10` ; do rm "$i" ; cnt=$(($cnt+1)) ; done ; echo $cnt > deleted_files_count.log
```

This doesn't check the content of the log file nor if it exists at all. If you want to properly handle possible errors, you will have to improve it a bit, but as long as you know that deleted_files_count.log exists and contains a number, it will do the trick.